# SQL Statement to get Unique vales and its count

Tags: sql-server

I have data in table as below:

Database is SQL Server
TABLE Name:   **Employee**

```
Emp_ID      EMP_name    Emp_Grade

101         Siddu           B
102         harsha          A
103         Patty           B
104         Preeti          A
105         Aarna           C
```

Can some one please help me to get out as below?

```
Emp_Grade   Count
B           2
A           2
C           1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What about `Group By`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Emp_Grade, Count(*) As [Count]
From Employee
Group by Emp_Grade
```

If you need the exact order then add

```
Order by [Count] desc, Emp_Grade desc
```